# how to select a constant value combined with subquery that returns multiple values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR
);
```

and run this query:

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT name FROM foo);
```

I expect the result to look something like this:

```
1    John
1    Jack
1    Jane
...
```

but instead I get an error

```
[21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

How can I make this work? PostgreSQL 10 if that matters.

UPDATE: The subquery is necessary, because it's a simplified case of a more complicated one.

Comment: Error: You have more than one results in your suquery

Comment: try `SELECT 1, name FROM foo;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you want is simpler:

```
SELECT 1, name
FROM foo;
```

You have a subquery in the `SELECT` clause.  This is a "scalar" subquery, that returns zero or one rows.  It can return more than one column (in Postgres).  In that case, the returned value is considered to be a tuple.

In any case, you don't want any of that.  If you want only one name, you can add `fetch first 1 row only` to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Error: You have more than one result in your subquery. You can try this

```
 SELECT 1, Name FROM foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because you are using a subselect, which can only return one row.

```
SELECT 1
```

would give you the result

> 1

Only one row. Now you are trying to use a subselect

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT Name FROM foo)
```

which would work if `foo` would only contain one row, if it returns more than one row, it wouldn't know what to (as in where to put the results fromt the subquery) and it throws an error instead.

You could try

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT string_agg(Name, ',') FROM foo)
```

if you'd want to recieve only one row, or

```
SELECT 1, Name FROM foo
```

if you want to recieve all results on a seperate row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select 1, name
from (select name from foo) subquery;
```